# await AggregateView.waitForLoadDone() sometimes blocks indefinitely when using SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After switching over to SVF2 `await aggregated.waitForLoadDone()` sometimes blocks indefinitely. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue deterministically. It can happen right after starting my app, after loading/unloading models or not at all.

I did not observe this behavior previously, but I wasn't able to (ab)use the viewer like this until now (eg. rapidly switching between very large models, some half-broken). Kudos for SVF2, performance is mind-boggling.

My current workaround is to `Promise.race` the `waitForLoadDone()` and reject after 10 seconds. This is working ok and keeps my app in a consistent state.

I have a suspicion that the problem might be network related.

*Edit:* I narrowed it down to the property `model.getData().loadDone` which sometimes remains `false` forever.

*Edit2:* This is getting worse with every release. I'm now on 7.60 and the viewer constantly breaks. Some objects never load, websockets get stuck and don't transfer any data, users need to manually clean their browser cache. How can this possibly pass any QA?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this could be - as you pointed out - a network issue. You may have noticed that the SVF2 format uses WebSockets to transfer the granular asset data to the browser, but if that persistent connection breaks, it's possible that the viewer wouldn't be able to recover.

Next time you see this happen, please check the console logs (and share them here if possible) and the network tab, to see if the WebSocket connection is still active. If it is, and the model still isn't loaded successfully, please submit a report to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` with as much info as possible so that we can debug it on our side.

Comment: Hi Petr! Thanks for your response. I'll try to debug this issue further and send you an email with my findings.